# need to re-write my code in less than O(n2) complexity

Tags: python, hashmap

I have an algorithm written which gives result.
Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

You can return the answer in any order.

But it is too slow,

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        res=[]
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            first_val=nums[i]
            second_val=target - nums[i]
            for j in range(len(nums)):
                if i!=j:
                    
                    if nums[j]==second_val:
                        res.append(i)
                        res.append(j)
                        return res
        return res
```

Could anyone assist me in rewriting this algorithm in Follow-up: Can you come up with an algorithm that is less than O(n2) time complexity?

Comment: SO doesn't solve homework problems (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), with some quick googling you can find plenty of answers and learn from it e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-a-and-a-number-x-check-for-pair-in-a-with-sum-as-x/

Comment: @mkrieger1 he's asking to rewrite it better than O(n²)

Comment: @mkrieger1 indeed, edit it, I don't have the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `O(n)` time complexity it can be done as below code.

logic is as, since there is solution pair in the given input, ie sum of these value make up to target, ie val1 + val2 = target, so we need to iterate through the list and search for val2 = target - val1, if we found it then return result.

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        info = {}
        for i, v in enumerate(nums):
            if target-v not in info:
                info[v] = i
            else:
                return [info[target-v], i]
```

Comment: `info` is an empty dict, so could you please explain, how can loop look inside it if there is `target-v`

Comment: you use dict/hashmap to store values and index only, ie if target-val is not yet found then instead of searching that value in list  ie `nums` which make O(n*2) time complexity, we save the current num value in this dict . and when we iterate through nums list , we search if `target-v`  is seen by us or not in this dictionary ie o(1) time process.  if that value is seen by us then we return the current index, and value (index) corresponds to another val

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in O(n) with a `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def two_sum(nums: list[int], target: int) -> tuple[int, int]:
    c = Counter(nums)
    for a in c:
        b = target - a
        if c[b] >= 1 + (a == b):
            return a, b
```

Building the `Counter` is O(n), iterating over it is also O(n), and checking for elements inside the iteration is O(1).

Comment: This is functionally different from OP's original question where the objective is to return the indexes of the values that sum to the target and not the values themselves